# Conditional probability - computing this when P(A and B) isn't clear.

Tags: probability

I am a bit confused with the definitions I have for conditional probability.

I have that P(A|B) = P(A $\cap$B) / P(B).

And I have P(A $\cap$ B) = P(A|B) P(B) (Follows by Algebra).

We also have that

P(A $\cap$ B) = P(A|B) P(B) = P(A)P(B) if A and B are independent.

But my confusion is that these are rather defined almost with each other. And I am not always sure if events are independent. How do I know how to compute P(A $\cap$ B) if it is not clear that an event is independent and I do not know anything about P(A|B)? Is this a case of me simply not understanding the problem?

Here's an example.

Urn A has four red, three blue, and two green balls. Urn B has two red, three blue, and four green balls.

A ball is drawn from A and put into B, and then a ball is drawn from B.

We let A = {r, r, r, r, b, b, b, g, g}

We let B = {r, r, b, b, b, g, g, g, g}

What is the probability that a red ball is drawn from Urn B?

Here's how I've tackled this problem. There are two cases - you either get a red ball from A or you don't. In either way, you increase the number of elements in B by one, so |B| = 10 when we draw from B (since we take a ball from A and put it into B). If it happens to be red, you know have 3 red and the probability changes, otherwise, you have more non-red and therefore a smaller chance of getting a red.

As a result, this hints that I should be using the law of total probability.

If we let

E1 = Event of getting a red ball from Urn A

E2 = Event of getting a red ball from Urn B

E3 = Event of getting a non-red ball from Urn A.

Then P(E2) = P(E2 | E1) + P(E2 | E3). Is this correct?

So now I compute P(E2 | E1) = P(E2 $\cap$ E1) / P(E1).

We have that P(E1) = 4 / 9.

Now P(E2 $\cap$ E1) = ?????

The way I understand this is the probability of getting both a red ball from urn A *and* the probability of getting a red ball from urn B, which is self-defining as that's the problem I'm trying to solve?

Even so, the way I see this is that I take a red ball from A and put it into B, that's the only way I can draw it from both urns. As such, the probability of getting a red from A = 4/9 and it follows that B = 3/10. So P(A and B) = (4/9) * (3/10). But how can I justify this? They aren't even independent for me to use this definition.

Comment: As a suggestion for future work, maybe you should label your events a little more systematically. You could have an event $B$ whose probability you want to compute, with various events $A_1,A_2,\dots$ upon which it depends. Here $B$ would be the event that you draw red in Urn B (sorry about that). $A_1$ would be the event that we drew red in Urn A, $A_2$ would be the complement, i.e., the event that we didn't draw red in Urn A. Sometimes you'll have more than 2 options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, your law of total probability (which is often called Bayes's Rule) should say:
$$P(E_2) = P(E_2|E_1)P(E_1) + P(E_2|E_3)P(E_3).$$
Note that you can reason out $P(E_2|E_1)$ without ever computing $P(E_1\cap E_2)$. As you already said, if the ball you drew from urn A was red, then the probability of drawing a red ball from urn B is $3/10$. Proceed.

Comment: Thank you! That is a critical error.

Comment: Nice explanation (+1). I just couldn't resist trying the the simulation.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is about the same as the Answer from @TedShifrin, but maybe my notation is easier to follow than yours.

Let $R_b$ be the even that you choose a red ball from urn B. Similarly, let $R_a$
be the event you choose a red ball from urn A. And so on.

The color of the ball from urn A partitions the sample space. That is
$R_a,\,B_a,$ and $G_a$ are exhaustive and mutually exclusive. Then use the
Law of Total Probability to get:

$$P(R_b) = P(R_b \cap R_a) + P(R_b \cap B_a) + P(R_b \cap G_a).$$
(Notice that $4/9 + 3/9 + 2/9 = 1.$)

Then use the General Multiplication Rule to get: 
$$P(R_b \cap R_a) = P(R_a)P(R_b | R_a) = (4/9)(3/10)$$ 
because having chosen a red ball from A you know there are 10 balls in B
of which 3 are now red. Do the same thing to evaluate 
$P(R_b \cap B_a)$ and $P(R_b \cap G_a).$

I admit you can do it just in terms of whether the ball from A is red or not,
giving only two sets in the partition, but maybe there is less chance of
a mistake my way.

---

Added later:

Here is a simulation from R statistical software. Essentially it does the experiment a million times
and keep track of the fraction of times you get a red ball from urn B.
(I used numbers instead of colors because R deals with numbers more
easily.)  With a million iterations, one can expect about two or three
place accuracy. The simulation gave 0.2443 and computation from the Law
of Total Probability gave 22/90 = 0.2444. Close enough for a check.

```
m = 10^6; x = w = numeric(m) 
for (i in 1:m) {
  a = c(1,1,1,1, 2,2,2, 3,3)    # 1 = red, 2 = blue 3 = green
  b = c(1,1, 2,2,2, 4,4,4,4)
  w[i] = xa = sample(a, 1)
  b2 = c(b, xa)
  x[i] = sample(b2, 1)  }       # color chosen from b
mean(x == 1)                    # prob of red from b
## 0.244316
22/90                           # compare
## 0.2444444
mean(w[x==1] == 1)
## 0.5455517
12/22                           # compare
## 0.5454545
```

Comment: I do like your approach but maybe I am unsure of how to do this, but how do I partition my sample space so I cover everything? I shy away from this approach because I feel uncomfortable with it, I admit.

Comment: I mentioned the partition because it is essential to using Bayes' Theorem.  For example, the next step, using Bayes' Theorem would be to ask, given that I got a red ball from B, what is the probability the ball transferred from A was red. Here the partition is easy: The ball from A is simply one of three colors, red, blue, or green. BTW: $P(R_a|R_b) = P(R_a \cap R_b)/P(R_b) = \frac{12/90}{22/90} = 12/22 = 0.5454.$ (I modified the simulation to keep track explicitly of the color of the ball from A. Simulated result 0.5455.) I can tell from this problem that you'll be doing Bayes' Theorem soon.